# Failed to build lanms-neo Polygon3

Tags: python, visual-c++, build, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, paddleocr

I have been trying to install paddleocr but the code exits with this error. I have tried multiple versions of VS Build Tools but the problem persists. Can someone help me solve this error, I have copied the error and output that the code exits with.

```
 × Building wheel for lanms-neo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lanms
      copying lanms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lanms
      running build_ext
      building 'lanms._C' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\lanms
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\lanms\csrc
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\lanms\csrc\clipper
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\hashm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1o2mkp67\lanms-neo_66c5d4de214a403c98599318fd36b821\lanms\csrc -IC:\Users\hashm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hsvxstut\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\hashm\miniconda3\envs\paddlenew\include -IC:\Users\hashm\miniconda3\envs\paddlenew\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /EHsc /Tplanms/csrc/clipper\clipper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\lanms/csrc/clipper\clipper.obj /std:c++latest /EHsc /bigobj
      clipper.cpp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open 
include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lanms-neo
  Building wheel for Polygon3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Using NumPy extension!
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Polygon
      copying Polygon\IO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Polygon
      copying Polygon\Shapes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Polygon
      copying Polygon\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Polygon
      copying Polygon\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\Polygon
      running build_ext
      building 'Polygon.cPolygon' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DDEFAULT_STYLE=STYLE_LIST -DWITH_NUMPY=1 -DSYSTEM_WIN32=1 -Isrc -IC:\Users\hashm\miniconda3\envs\paddlenew\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\hashm\miniconda3\envs\paddlenew\include -IC:\Users\hashm\miniconda3\envs\paddlenew\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /Tcsrc/PolyUtil.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src/PolyUtil.obj
      PolyUtil.c
      c:\users\hashm\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-1o2mkp67\polygon3_b44d80ca5d45474bae4cb9f6604164ba\src\gpc.h(36): fatal error C1083: Cannot open 
include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and I have tried VS build tools 2017, 2019, 2022, but I cannot successfully install paddleocr.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of polygon3 and lanms installation issue do this :-

```
!apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Comment: ufff.. saved my life today! Thanks a lot! :D